# How can I run a query and show the result in laravel backpack?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have 3 tables.

```
Table Student : id , name 
Table question : id , question , choice1,choice2, correctChoice,questionPoint
Table StudentAnswer: id, student_id,question_id,choice
```

I want to measure student point base on their Answers and show results on the right side of students' name in backpack laravel. Is it possible and is there a way in laravel backpack for that?
I know that I can use a query to measure student point but I want to know how to show results in laravel backpack?
And what is the best solution for a scalable site?
thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited my question and correct it. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don’t need to order the table by that calculated attribute, I recommend you use a function on the Student Model to return the point base.

You’ll then be able to show that function using the model_function column type in Backpack - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-columns#model_function